# Is or are, Include or includes?

Tags: grammatical-number

Reported in Panel B **is or are** fund information, which **include or includes** the number of funds and managers.

Can someone kindly help with the grammar in this sentence.Which is actually is the subject? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/information) states that

> Information is an uncountable noun

so the correct usage would be "information is", in the same way that "[news is](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/news) " or "water is". For the same reason, the second part of your sentence would be "which includes".

The subject is "fund information", as you can see if you rewrite your sentence like this: *Fund information is reported in panel B*.

Answer (score -1):

For the first part I would say "is" considering that "fund information" is a singular form. As for the second it would be "includes" in light of the plural in "Funds and managers"